# Android Gps AsyncTask And ProgressDialog indeterminate

Tags: java, android, gps, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to do something like this:

```
public class Gps {

public void getLatitude(){}

public void getLongitude(){}

}
```

But using `AsyncTask` and `ProgressDialog` indeterminate to get location position.

I have a class like my example, but when I add a GPS listener I use `requestSingleUpdate` method from `LocationManager` to retrieve a location at once. I want to implement this using `AsyncTask` to get GPS position at once and show progress dialog indeterminate when retrieving location.

Answer (score 0):

Do you look for something like this?!

```
public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a class like my exemple, but when i add a gps listener, i use
 requestSingleUpdate method from LocationManager to retrieve a location at once, i want to implement this using AsyncTask to get gps position at once, and show progress dialog indeterminate when retrieving location, thanks in advance...